# Android Edittext keypress does not fire

Tags: android, keypress, barcode-scanner, enter, onkeylistener

I am trying to get Enter key whenever user pressed.

I tried many codes but neither in emulator nor in device I could get the Enter keypress.

Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnKeyListener {
String barkodsifre;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText sifre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.barkodsifre);
    sifre.setOnKeyListener(this);
}
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
        Log.i("a","b");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

There is only 1 edittext and a textview in xml. Data will be entered to edittext by a barcode scanner. Barcode scanner will send "Enter" at the end of the scanned barcode. 
I send 'enter' from barcode scanner at the end of the barcode but somehow it never handles enter key.

Is something missed in code or the code is totaly wrong? How can I handle "enter" key which comes from a barcode scanner.

Here is my xml :

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblbarkod"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:text="Barkod Giriniz!"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/barkodsifre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lblbarkod"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblbarkod"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lblbarkod"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lblbarkod"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblbarkod"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo|flagNoFullscreen"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override <----------------!!!!!
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
        Log.i("a","b");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand your answer. If you meant I need to write override above Onkey method, I did it and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EditText.OnKeyListener {
    String barkodsifre;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText sifre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.barkodsifre);
        sifre.setOnKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            Log.i("a","b");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText sifre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.barkodsifre);
sifre.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    Log.i("a",s.toString());
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

  }
});
```